# What tree do these little white flowers grow on?

Tags: identification, trees, flowers

My first guess was apricot, but google showed that that's wrong. Sorry for the somewhat tangential question. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any more information on this tree? Where is it located? Do you have a photo of the leaves? My best guess would be a plum or an apple, based on the spur length and color/appearance of the blossoms, but it would be nice to have a leaf photo to help.

Comment: @michelle Thanks! (Unfortunately I did not take this photo. It's all I have.)

Comment: @michelle - as a guess, I'd vote for apple, too, mostly from what is visible from the bark. Cherry is a lot smoother...

Comment: @Stephie Apples bloom after the leaves come out though. And the apple twigs are more robust.  Could be plum...

Comment: @J.Musser Well, if it's not apple, my next guess is plum. It doesn't look like a pear, plumcot, apricot, quince, cherry, etc. to me. (Although that doesn't mean it's not.) Peach is a possibility.

Comment: @Readingtao Can you show us a picture of the bark on the tree (its trunk and growth habit)? That would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple Blossom - "Malus domestica" is my best guess.
There is not really enough info in the photo to distinguish between and apple "Malus" and crabapple "Crataegus".  However it is more likely an apple blossom due to the color of the blossoms, the apparent arrangement of them (fasciculate  or bundled; rather than corymbose or flat-shaped but starting at different points on the stem), number of stamens and their color, and my guess as to the shape and nature of the leaves in the background.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the tree is an apple :) here a picture taked from [here](http://www.50states.com/flower/arkansas.htm#.VihEuPmqqko)

[image]